# selenium and single page application

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a third party developed Single Page Application website. i have to write test this site by selenium.

About the website After login it has many menus and sub menus, manually im clicking a page and feeding inputs.

I have to achieve the above work by selenium from Chrome browser.

1. Now, using C# and Selenium, im able to login and able to click Menu then sub menu but, when i try to find the input controls By Id Or By Name or By Xpath it always says the content is not found.

2.so, #1 is failed then I followed another method, After login rather than clicking Menu and SUb Menu, i directily moved into the Page by using URL now, i'm able to Finding the controls by id/Name/Xpath but, there is a button to open a popup, when i click it the page is just refreshed.

Experts please advice what is the problem by using method 1 and 2.

This is my code bellow:

```
IJavaScriptExecutor jsCompanySearch = chromeDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string strScript = "<script type='text/javascript'> var URLProfileSearch = '/folder/folder/folder/pagename.aspx'; var URLCompanySearch = 'somepage.aspx'; var NumberOfDecimalPlaces=2; CompanySearch('tc_tp_Main_cs_Company_winp_CompanyRef','COMSEARCHUSERCONTROL', '', 'tc_tp_Main_cs_Company_btn_Dummy');return false;</script>";
jsCompanySearch.ExecuteScript(strScript);
Thread.Sleep(10000);
```

Thank you

Comment: any code? can't do much with this

Comment: may be you need to wait some times after login

Comment: Could you please provide more information? After page load, could you do a Thread.Sleep for 5 seconds and then locate the elements? Then we know if this is a timing issue or not.

Comment: Hello All, by method #1 Yes i put Thread.Sleep for 10 seconds after page load also increased sleep time but, no luck

Comment: by method#2 im able to finding the controls but, the only problem is when  clicking the <a> button the popup is not opening. Actually when i click it manually (after opened the page indivudualy) then also its not opening popup. below is source code

Comment: IJavaScriptExecutor jsCompanySearch = chromeDriver as IJavaScriptExecutor;
string strScript = "<script type='text/javascript'> var URLProfileSearch = '/folder/folder/folder/pagename.aspx'; var URLCompanySearch = 'somepage.aspx'; var NumberOfDecimalPlaces=2; CompanySearch('tc_tp_Main_cs_Company_winp_CompanyRef','COMSEARCHUSERCONTROL', '', 'tc_tp_Main_cs_Company_btn_Dummy');return false;</script>";
jsCompanySearch.ExecuteScript(strScript);
Thread.Sleep(10000); I clicked by Javascript and button click but, popup is not opening.